# Is the usage of the word 'resounding' correct here?

Tags: word-usage

I awkwardly used the word 'resounding' a while ago as follows. Your argument is resounding. I meant you raised a good point there, although at the time I went for that strange statement. Anyway, was that, by any means, correct? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of "[resounding](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/resounding)" can be "clear, emphatic, unmistakeable", so if you meant the word in this context, I'd say it's fine.

I'd also consider:

> Your argument is astoundingly good **OR** Your argument is valid (etc)

Note that in my experience "resounding" usually collocates with "success".

> The event was a resounding success.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I was hoping the message delivered with the vibe of "make sense" (as in loud enough). But, I think we only used that for a sound or something. I messed up the word usage. If only, I posted it here earlier and get your feedback.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't be so hard on yourself. We use the connotations/analogy of sound in a lot of situations. Think of a room full of people slowly realising the excellence of the person's argument. We could certainly use "resounding" to describe this effect of realisation.

Answer (score 0):

Thus the google translator was good enough in this case.  "Resounding argument" is the literal translation of the Dutch "doorslaand argument", I noticed.  I'll use it to replace "crucial factors", that were not really the right words to use in the context!